# I want to connect contract without using meta mask

Tags: backend, blockchain, contract

want to show contract information for some people but  don't want to use meta mask-before  used meta mask and web3 and it work-now  want  when customer check our site(html/java scrips Front end for contract) they never install meta mask and just look at information that load from contract. please help me.

before i used this code but in the other browser people see error for ethereum :

```js
<script>

            if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') 
            {
                console.log('MetaMask is installed!');                  
            }else{
                console.log('MetaMask not installed!');
                alert("Please install Metamsk wallet first, then try again");
                 }  
            const accounts = ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const account = accounts[0];
            const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9c81.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers to my questions.
I Have to Use Infura from  this [page](https://infura.io/)

please check this [information](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-setup-your-dapps-to-not-use-metamask-plugin-but-sign-the-transaction-backend-b8cb8808c9ae)

and at first You have to create project in [infura](https://infura.io/) and get ID

and use this code :

```js
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3c68e/*Your Own ID*/1753"));
```